Which is the difference between Worker service and timer to run a periodic code?
I want to develop a windows service that many requesters to request files to different remote compters.
For to simplify, here I will talk about two remote compters.
For that, I have created a windows service project and the base code is this:
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

I can see that the worker is run inside an inifite loop and use a delay to run it periodically.
At first, I was thinking to create a requester manager that would create all the needed requesters and run it. For that, I would create a System.Threading.Timer to run each requester to the interval in which is configured.
Something like that:
public class RequesterManager()
{
   List<Timer> _timers = [];


   public class RequesterManater(IEnumerable<RequestersConfiguration> paramRquestersConfiguration)
   {
      //Create timers and add it to the _timers collection.
   }
}



public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly RequestersManager _requestersManager;


    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

            public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Create requestersManager
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Dispoise requesterManager
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
}

But after seeing that the worker service can be run periodically, using an infinite loop and a delay to way until next execution, I was thinking if I could use the work service instead of the timers to run the requesters periodically.
Which is the difference between the work service and timer?
Thanks.

The worker service isn't run periodically. The generic host finds all classes that implement IHostedService, creates them as singletons and calls their StartAsync at app startup and StopAsync at the end. In the first snippet you're awaiting in a loop, not running periodically. BTW Task.Delay uses a timer internally. Check the Timed background service example, which uses a timer to do the same thing you propose

The BackgroundService class adds code that calls ExecuteAsync when the host calls StartAsync and stores the task, then signals the cancellation token source when StopAsync is called

Task.Delay is a wrapper around a timer. So a timer and a loop around Task.Delay does more or less the same thing. I tend to prefer a timer since it better communicates the intent, but you can use whatever you prefer.
What you need to consider is if the period should include the time to do the work or not. Most timers just tick at a fixed period, regardless of how long the work takes, and this may cause multiple concurrent executions of the work.
A loop around Task.Delay will have period of worktime + delayTime, so avoids these concurrency issues. But you could do the same by calling Threading.Timer.Change each tick. Or you could use a periodic timer if that better suits your needs. If the work takes a insignificant amount of time this should not really matter.

Thanks so much. One doubt. I have read that PeriodicTimer is very accurate, but what happens if the task take more time than the interval? For your suggest to use PeriodicTimer, it seems that it is similar to loop Task.Delay, that it waits until the task is finished.

You can also try/stop timer, finally/start timer if you want a timer approach that pauses ticking while the work is done..

@ÁlvaroGarcía PeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync would presumably wait for the next tick, read the documentation for details. Note that all timers use the same underlying OS mechanism for time keeping, so a ~16ms resolution on windows by default.
